# Unable to disable image button inside jquery in chrome

Tags: jquery, telerik

Unable to disable image button inside jquery in chrome

In side cshtml page code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<object>().Name("testGrid").Columns(columns =>{
columns.Bound(item).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' width='20px' onchange=testGrid.OnPriceLockChange(this)' class='price' /><img src='" + @Url.Content("~/images/Tier/PlusT.png") + "' width='16' height='16' border='0' alt='Add Tier' title='Add Tier' onclick=testGrid.OnAddTierClick(this);' />").Title("Lock").Width(120);
```

Inside Jquery-

```
$.each(rows, function (index, row) {
var images = row.find("img");
$.each(images, function (index, image) {
  $(image).attr("disabled", "disabled");
     });
}
```

This code Is working in IE, but not wokring in Chrome.

I have tried `$(image).attr("disabled", true);` also, but not working in chrome.

Only `$(image).removeAttr("onclick");` is working in Chrome as well as IE.

But after that unable to bind `onclick` again.

Please give some suggestion that how can disable the button inside jquery in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable images. Only for input fields it's build in (standardized).

Also the `onclick=testGrid.OnAddTierClick(this);` is not the preferred way to attach onClick handlers. It's the old and lazy way. The jquery way is better / easier to maintain and logic is loose coupled from the view (html).

The disable checking is not build in so check it yourself. Here is an example.

ex html:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/16x16" alt="Add Tier" title="Add Tier" class="addTierButton"/>
```

javascript:

```
$('.addTierButton').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('disabled') !== true){
        //onAddTierClick logic here...
    }
});
```

or even shorter:

```
$('.addTierButton[disabled!="true"]').click(function(){
        //onAddTierClick logic here...
});
```

if you want to add rows and keep the binding you use `.on()`

```
$(_selector_for_parent_container_).on('click','.addTierButton[disabled!="true"]', function(){
        //onAddTierClick logic here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks    $(image).attr("onclick", "").unbind("click"); is also working for me

Answer (score 0):

VDP's answer is great!  I used the following, which worked like a charm.

```
if ($('#' + controlid + '_Image1').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') return;
```